# Help on understanding the norm of linear transformation.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

In my textbook, the norm is defined as:

> For each $L\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{E}^n,\mathbb{E}^m)$ we define a norm
>   by
>
> $$\|L\|=\inf\{K \mid \|L(\mathbf{x})\| \leq K\|\mathbf{x}\|
> \forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{E}^n \}$$

Does this mean we have to find smallest $K$ that makes the inequality true?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite dimensional, this is the same as $\displaystyle\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\|Lx\|}{\|x\|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loosely speaking, yes. I say 'loosely' because the set $$ \{K : \| L (x) \| \le K \|x\|\, \forall x \in \mathbb E^n\} $$ may not have a smallest element. For instance, it could be a half-open interval. However, it will always have a greatest lower bound.

Also, if $\mathbb E$ is finite-dimensional (like, say, the real line), then the set shown above will always have a smallest element.

Comment: Is it possible for the norm to be $-\infty$? If you the set $\{K : \| L (x) \| \le K \|x\|\, \forall x \in \mathbb E^n\}$ didn't have a smallest element, the infimum of the set will $-\infty$ right?

Comment: @user3000482 No. The norm on $\mathcal L (\mathbb E^n, \mathbb E^m ) $ is a proper norm, which means that it is always greater than or equal to $0$, because the set you are taking the infimum of, when non-empty, will never include a negative number, and hence will always be bounded below by $0$. If the set is empty (there is no $K$ for which the inequality is true), then the infimum is $\infty$.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, can you give an example where there's no smallest element of this set?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, but I don't know if $\mathbb E$ is finite-dimensional :)

Comment: Huh, $\Bbb E^n$ is standardly $n$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Some people do use it to refer to an $n$-Euclidean space, but it certainly isn't as unambiguous as $\mathbb R^n$. But yes, sure, if the OP is talking about Euclidean spaces, then it is always the case that $\| L \| < \infty$.

Comment: That wasn't my point. In the finite-dimensional case, the inf of that set is always its minimum element.

Comment: Aha. Yes, of course. This is what I get for being on MSE at 1 AM. However, you could've just said that in the first place. Editing answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin I never saw this notation.